# Problem with excel opening, editing and file creasting and writing

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I need to systematically analyze a lot of excel files in specific folder to be specific do the following:

1. Open the excel file
2. create a histogram based on a specific column called "Feret"
3. calculate the stats: avg, min and max
4. save the histogram and stats to the same excel file
5. save the histogram as an image following the excel file name
6. create a word file in the same folder following the same excel file name
7. add the histogram and the statistical data to this word (as a report).
8. do this to all the excel files in the folder until they all finished.

I have used my basic knowledge along with chatgpt. The code is running but does not do the job.in specific after running the code,the excel files does not include the stats, nor the histogram is constructed. Accordingly,  the histogram does not save an image. Also the word file is not created at all.

Thank you!

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from docx import Document

def plot_histogram(file_path, column_name='Feret', bandwidth=3):
    try:
        # Read Excel file into a pandas DataFrame
        df = pd.read_excel(r'file path')

        # Extract the specified column and convert to numeric values
        df[column_name] = pd.to_numeric(df[column_name], errors='coerce')
        df = df.dropna(subset=[column_name])

        # Extract the specified column
        feret_values = df[column_name]

        # Plot histogram
        plt.hist(feret_values, bins='auto', alpha=0.7, rwidth=0.85, density=True)
        plt.title(f'Histogram of {column_name}')
        plt.xlabel(column_name)
        plt.ylabel('Frequency')

        # Save the plot as an image (optional)
        plot_filename = f"{os.path.splitext(file_path)[0]}_{column_name}_histogram.png"
        plt.savefig(plot_filename)

        # Close the plot to avoid displaying in the script (optional)
        plt.close()

        return plot_filename, feret_values

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error in plot_histogram: {e}")
        return None, None

def update_excel_with_statistics(file_path, column_name, statistics, plot_filename):
    try:
        # Read Excel file into a pandas DataFrame
        df = pd.read_excel(file_path)

        # Update the Excel file with statistics
        df_statistics = pd.DataFrame(statistics, index=[0])

        # Append the statistics and plot filename to the original DataFrame
        df = pd.concat([df, df_statistics], axis=1)

        # Save the updated DataFrame to Excel
        df.to_excel(file_path, index=False)

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error in update_excel_with_statistics: {e}")

def create_word_document(file_path, column_name, statistics, histogram_image):
    try:
        # Create a new Word document
        doc = Document()

        # Add a title
        doc.add_heading('Histogram Results', level=1)

        # Add statistics to the document
        doc.add_heading('Statistics:', level=2)
        doc.add_paragraph(f"File Name: {os.path.basename(file_path)}")
        doc.add_paragraph(f"Column Name: {column_name}")
        doc.add_paragraph(f"Average Feret: {statistics['average']:.2f}")
        doc.add_paragraph(f"Max Feret: {statistics['max']:.2f}")
        doc.add_paragraph(f"Min Feret: {statistics['min']:.2f}")

        # Add a section for the histogram plot
        doc.add_heading('Histogram Plot:', level=2)

        if histogram_image:
            doc.add_picture(histogram_image, width=doc.shared.Inches(6))
        else:
            doc.add_paragraph("Histogram plot not available.")

        # Save the Word document
        output_word_file = f"{os.path.splitext(file_path)[0]}_{column_name}_histogram_results.docx"
        doc.save(output_word_file)

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error in create_word_document: {e}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    folder_path = '.'  # Change this to the path of your folder containing Excel files

    for file_name in os.listdir(folder_path):
        if file_name.endswith('.xlsx'):
            file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, file_name)

            # Specify the column name and bandwidth
            column_name = 'Feret'
            bandwidth = 3

            # Plot the histogram and get the plot filename and feret values
            plot_filename, feret_values = plot_histogram(file_path, column_name, bandwidth)

            if plot_filename is not None:
                # Calculate statistics
                statistics = {
                    'average': feret_values.mean(),
                    'max': feret_values.max(),
                    'min': feret_values.min()
                }

                # Print statistics for debugging
                print(f"Statistics for {file_path}: {statistics}")

                # Update the Excel file with statistics and plot filename
                update_excel_with_statistics(file_path, column_name, statistics, plot_filename)

                # Create and save individual Word documents with the histogram results and statistics
                create_word_document(file_path, column_name, statistics, plot_filename)

                print(f"Processing for {file_path} completed.")
            else:
                print(f"Skipping {file_path} due to an error in plot_histogram.")
```

Comment: You have to ask **one** question at a time. What exactly doesn't work? Start with the first issue.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.